# django include template into other templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I can`t correctly include "mainslider.html" in my index.html as
{% include "pages/mainslider.html" %}

my index page **views**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

i can see my slider at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/slider/` , but nothing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

it is slider code:
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from easy_thumbnails.fields import ThumbnailerImageField

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    meta_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    meta_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    device = RichTextField()
    image = ThumbnailerImageField( upload_to = 'media')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/works/%i/" % self.id

class Slider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 500)
    image = ThumbnailerImageField( upload_to = 'media')
    whichslide = models.ForeignKey('Portfolio')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
class SliderListView(ListView):
    model = Slider
    context_object_name = 'sliders'
    template_name = 'pages/mainslider.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SliderListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['portfolio'] = Portfolio.objects.all()
    return context
```

**mainslider.html**

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider">
{% for slider in sliders %}
  <li>
    <img src="{{ slider.image.mainslider.url }}" alt="{{ slider.whichslide.title }}">
    <p class="caption">{{ slider.title }}</p>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and some **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^slider/$', SliderListView.as_view(), name="slider_list"),
```

Comment: Including the template is not enough. If you want everything to be visible on index.html you also need to pass the data to the template in the context of the index view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Simein Visser said, you have to include the data in the index view.

One simple solution could be use that instead your `index` function:

```
class Index(SliderListView):
    # you're reusing the context data included by SliderListView view
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Comment: Yep,i did it! Thanks you guys!